# How to set up VSCode proxy on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, proxy

I've got Ubuntu 20.04 and VSCode 1.49.3 installed.

I'm working behind a corporate proxy, so I set up my proxy settings without specifying my login and password, i.e. http://proxy.domain.com

After I run VSCode it asked me for proxy login and password. (BTW it asked me twice, why?) Then I clicked "Check for updates" and it said that there are no updates. Seems OK, but browsing extensions fails for unknown reason.

After I close VSCode and run it again, VSCode asked me for login/password again. It seems like it doesn't store my credentials. Why?

I also tried to use "http://login:password@proxy.domain.com" that works with `wget`. It doesn't work with VSCode for unknown reason, VSCode fails to check for updates with "timeout" error.

[image]

[image]